# Spring boot reactive redis connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, reactive, rsocket

I am new to redis reactive implementation. I am trying to setup a backend which utilises redis on localhost:6379 (default location). Now the [documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-reactive) stated "We do not need to add any code for configuration if want to connect to a Redis server at localhost:6379."

So i started my redis as usual:

[image]

made a simple post request

```
{
    "uid":"123",
    "message":"hello world"
}
```

to this controller

```
@PostMapping("/api/v1/space/post/")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> postMessage(@RequestBody Message message) throws Exception {
    if(messageService.postMessage(message.getUid(), message.getMessage())){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("it works!");
    } else{
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("something's wrong");
    }
    
}
```

Everything went fine, the log even stated that the hash has been created. But, when i do redis-cli and check for any keys, nothing is there.

[image]

I also tried to connect using LettuceConnectionFactory

```
    @Bean
public ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory reactiveRedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory("localhost", 6379);
}
```

Yet no luck, I am guessing that the spring boot is somehow connected to an embedded redis which is not what I want, so how do I connect to a redis instance?

**EDIT**

Here are is the message repo & service
The repo returns a MonoIgnorePublisher, in the documentation, Mono either returns an element or error, is this an error? :

Repo:

```
private final ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Message> redisTemplate;

    public MessageRepository(ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Message> redisOperations) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisOperations;
    }

    public Mono<Void> save(String authorId, String msg) {
        Message message = new Message(authorId, msg);
        Mono<Void> res = Mono.when(redisTemplate.<String, Message>opsForHash().put("space", message.getId(), message), 
        redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(message.getUid(), message, message.getTimestamp().toEpochDay())).then();
        System.out.println(res.toString());
        return res;
    }
```

Service:

```
    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository repo;
public Boolean postMessage(String authorId, String msg) throws Exception {
        try{
            repo.save(authorId, msg);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return true;       
    }
```

Here is the ReactiveRedisOperation config:

```
@Bean
public ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Message> redisOperations(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory factory) {
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Message> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Message.class);

    RedisSerializationContext.RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, Message> builder = RedisSerializationContext
            .newSerializationContext(new StringRedisSerializer());

    RedisSerializationContext<String, Message> context = builder.value(serializer)
            .hashKey(new StringRedisSerializer()).hashValue(serializer).build();

    return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(factory, context);
}
```

Comment: There's no mention of any embedded redis instance. What does `messageService` look like? The bug is probably there and your write isn't succeeding.

Comment: @Kayaman hi, thank you for the input, I have edited my question, I do think it's due to the repo, I have no clue what it is though.

Answer (score 0):

Please use property key as spring.redis.port and spring.redis.host. It will work.